# How to PyTest, Mixer, Django, OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, pytest

As suggested by most Django tutorials, I made my own User model via `AbstractUser` and also created a `Profile`-model with further details like a bio which is linked to `User` via a OneToOneField.

Now I'm starting to write tests and I am not sure how to reference the `Profile` Model from within there.

**test_models.py**

```
import pytest
from mixer.backend.django import mixer

pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db


class TestUsers:

    def test_user(self):
        obj = mixer.blend('player.User')

        assert obj.pk == 1, 'Should save one instance of a user'
        assert obj.Profile.bio is not None, 'There should be at least default bio'
```

Which get's me an `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'Profile'

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=130, default='No bio written yet.')

@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

How do I reference the profile that should have been created via the signals in models.py for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it. My new test_models.py file reads like that:

```
import pytest
from mixer.backend.django import mixer
from player.models import Profile

pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db


class TestUsers:

    def test_user(self):
        obj = mixer.blend('player.User')
        prof = Profile.objects.get(user_id=1)
        prof.bio = 'Testbio'
        prof.save()
        prof = Profile.objects.get(user_id=1)
        assert obj.pk == 1, 'Should save one instance of a user'
        assert prof.bio == 'Testbio'
```

I create a User, I grab his Profile from the database, I change the bio and save it back to the database. I grab the changed version from the database and check if the changed bio is in there.

If there is a more elegant way of doing this, I'd be happy to read that.